# Call to undefined function mysql_connect() after upgrading to php5.5.50A4

Tags: php, deprecated

I have upgraded to PHP 5.5.0Alpha 4 via the windows binaries: http://windows.php.net/qa/

the php_mysql.dll is present and uncommented in my php.ini but it's still throwing an undefined function.

The reason for using the development package is to prove to a group of "developers" that the mysql_* is officially generating depreciation warnings within this development package. BUT I cannot call the mysql_* functions.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "xxx"); 
mysql_select_db("test");
```

errors:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 4
```

The errors should be generated when a successfull connection to a mysql database is established.  Proof:

> - MySQL   . This extension is now deprecated, and deprecation warnings will be generated
>     when connections are established to databases via mysql_connect(),
>     mysql_pconnect(), or through implicit connection: use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL
>     instead (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). (Adam)

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.5.0alpha4/NEWS

Comment: Well it's still an alpha release... Can't expect everything right ^^

Comment: Isn't this better? You can prove them that mysql_* functions don't even work anymore :)

Answer (score 2):

This is still a development/beta build and should be treated as extremely experimental as far as the proof goes... You should just point them to any mysql_* extension on the PHP.net page, you will notice the depreciation warning.

Then go ahead and forward them to a function which has already been depreciated from PHP, such as `ereg()` you will notice essentially the same red box warning.

as far as your error message, if you are 100% sure that your extensions are present in your `ext/` folder, and are uncommented from your PHP.ini; and have restarted your apache service.. Then the problem resticides within the actual .dll extension, as this is an experimental/beta build, nothing is guaranteed to work 100%...

and as for the proof; point them to php.net and link them the mysql_* functions and the news file.